# Create or update Automation with Marketing Cloud REST API new endpoint

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, oauth2, automationstudio, automation

there is an endpoint to retrieve automation using Rest API with OAuth2 token and GET method:

```
https://{{tenant}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/automation/v1/automations/{{id}}
```

In the response you will get an automation in .json format:

```
{
    "id": "6d502423-ddf4-4c54-abbe-f5c3f2cfcb49",
    "name": "Tracking Extract Report",
    "description": "",
    "key": "af759c22-9271-1e75-f695-5f79de858e8a",
    "typeId": 1,
    "type": "scheduled",
    "statusId": 4,
    "status": "PausedSchedule",
    "categoryId": 681,
    "lastRunTime": "2019-04-26T05:31:46.21",
    "lastRunInstanceId": "5a889ff1-7823-457e-a17b-a0c3d879091c",
    "schedule": {
        "id": "111fdd2e-a68d-4117-5a60-322beb3436dc",
        "typeId": 2,
        "startDate": "2019-04-11T18:30:00",
        "endDate": "2079-06-06T00:00:00",
        "scheduledTime": "0001-01-01T07:00:00",
        "rangeTypeId": 1,
        "occurrences": 527286,
        "pattern": "<Pattern><PatternType>0</PatternType><HourInterval>1</HourInterval></Pattern>",
        "icalRecur": "FREQ=HOURLY;UNTIL=20790606T080000;INTERVAL=1",
        "timezoneName": "Romance Standard Time",
        "scheduleStatus": "paused",
        "timezoneId": 7
    },
    "steps": [
        {
            "id": "fa8452cb-455b-427e-bd03-22f3be317cba",
            "name": "",
            "step": 1,
            "activities": [
                {
                    "id": "584e75ae-ee58-472b-b689-9def0c25eaba",
                    "name": "Extract Reports Creation",
                    "activityObjectId": "05d87588-19d3-4829-bf4b-c1a5c2e5d2a9",
                    "objectTypeId": 73,
                    "displayOrder": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "bc31b39d-5b71-4cd8-b56c-948009876a28",
            "name": "",
            "step": 2,
            "activities": [
                {
                    "id": "83b7cc0a-b0c0-45f9-9547-d8d6cd9fde79",
                    "name": "Export Tracking Report To FTP",
                    "activityObjectId": "0a955058-55de-47a0-a95e-4a338a564bb7",
                    "objectTypeId": 53,
                    "displayOrder": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "4b828cab-1216-4859-bb24-d329a89f080d",
            "name": "",
            "step": 3,
            "activities": [
                {
                    "id": "6c33d219-75bc-4fe2-968a-5fbaa46fee4a",
                    "name": "Unzip_Tracking_Report",
                    "activityObjectId": "a050199d-d7b3-4f04-9d3c-c3208f32c50c",
                    "objectTypeId": 53,
                    "displayOrder": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "d23dfc81-0a55-4ee9-8265-9aff4b85ab92",
            "name": "",
            "step": 4,
            "activities": [
                {
                    "id": "5e0eaa08-853e-4ecc-8490-4250b2e062f2",
                    "name": "Import_TrackingExtract_SendJobs",
                    "activityObjectId": "3125f806-1b15-e911-a2d0-1402ec8ca115",
                    "objectTypeId": 43,
                    "displayOrder": 1,
                    "targetDataExtensions": [
                        {
                            "id": "284c8568-1515-e911-a2d0-1402ec8ca115",
                            "name": "TrackingExtract_SendJobs",
                            "key": "D5C31190-611A-4817-9CBF-D023E1D9B646",
                            "description": "",
                            "rowCount": 129
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "0d43fe57-3b10-4953-a9e2-c230903061c0",
                    "name": "Import_TrackingExtract_Sent",
                    "activityObjectId": "c7d5f633-6f15-e911-a2d0-1402ec8ca115",
                    "objectTypeId": 43,
                    "displayOrder": 2,
                    "targetDataExtensions": [
                        {
                            "id": "a40e718b-6c55-e911-a2d0-1402ec8ca115",
                            "name": "TrackingExtract_Sent",
                            "key": "E054D3A6-720A-4A67-A737-28231B52ACFC",
                            "description": "",
                            "rowCount": 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "6ae75778-52ad-4dea-85f5-92ed017694c8",
                    "name": "Import_TrackingExtract_Opens",
                    "activityObjectId": "21223554-6f15-e911-a2d0-1402ec8ca115",
                    "objectTypeId": 43,
                    "displayOrder": 3,
                    "targetDataExtensions": [
                        {
                            "id": "52935236-6d15-e951-a2d0-1402ec8ca115",
                            "name": "TrackingExtract_Opens",
                            "key": "D2FED15B-DB4F-42DC-8025-F628C583ABA0",
                            "description": "",
                            "rowCount": 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "7c400533-47e1-4bff-bc5a-8868b6db18dd",
                    "name": "Import_TrackingExtract_Clicks",
                    "activityObjectId": "c88455ef-6f15-e911-a2d0-1402ec8ca115",
                    "objectTypeId": 43,
                    "displayOrder": 4,
                    "targetDataExtensions": [
                        {
                            "id": "3ec69c9e-6515-e911-a2d0-1402ec8ca115",
                            "name": "TrackingExtract_Clicks",
                            "key": "1D424B60-49C8-43FC-89A8-CD4000BE114F",
                            "description": "",
                            "rowCount": 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "bde26ad7-50b1-4f5b-b15b-2222ac072e6e",
                    "name": "Import_TrackingExtract_Bounces",
                    "activityObjectId": "fcf75f09-7015-e911-a2d0-1402ec8ca115",
                    "objectTypeId": 43,
                    "displayOrder": 5,
                    "targetDataExtensions": [
                        {
                            "id": "bc56343e-6515-e911-a2d0-1402ec8ca115",
                            "name": "TrackingExtract_Bounces",
                            "key": "F3578B67-AEEC-4C2B-8099-D621ECD7F22B",
                            "description": "",
                            "rowCount": 2
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "142f4ce3-1534-4056-a1be-e7ef79546e43",
                    "name": "Import_TrackingExtract_NotSent",
                    "activityObjectId": "5d65ce75-7115-e911-a2d0-1402ec8ca115",
                    "objectTypeId": 43,
                    "displayOrder": 6,
                    "targetDataExtensions": [
                        {
                            "id": "06e55e39-7115-e911-a2d0-1402ec8ca115",
                            "name": "TrackingExtract_NotSent",
                            "key": "CBCCCA93-D0D8-4CD8-B3FF-8C891410AC9D",
                            "description": "",
                            "rowCount": 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "3aa11ca3-14b7-457f-97eb-8e53b2c3c1ba",
                    "name": "Import_TrackingExtract_Unsubs",
                    "activityObjectId": "c529bfc2-7915-e911-a2d0-1402ec8ca115",
                    "objectTypeId": 43,
                    "displayOrder": 7,
                    "targetDataExtensions": [
                        {
                            "id": "9cb22265-7915-e911-a2d0-1402ec8ca115",
                            "name": "TrackingExtract_Unsubs",
                            "key": "8B7126DC-4776-4751-8581-3E1C1C7A9BBD",
                            "description": "",
                            "rowCount": 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "4596f1ba-dba5-45cd-9546-11d05d176616",
                    "name": "Import_TrackingExtract_Surveys",
                    "activityObjectId": "35e897a2-7d15-e911-a2d0-1402ec8ca115",
                    "objectTypeId": 43,
                    "displayOrder": 8,
                    "targetDataExtensions": [
                        {
                            "id": "f25c1d45-7d15-e911-a2d0-1402ec8ca115",
                            "name": "TrackingExtract_Surveys",
                            "key": "AEAED33D-FBE1-44CD-BB9B-9DEDF788116D",
                            "description": "",
                            "rowCount": 0
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

There is also a POST method to create a new Automation with the endpoint:

```
https://{{tenant}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/automation/v1/automations/
```

and a PATCH method to update an existing Automation with the endpoint:

```
https://{{tenant}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/automation/v1/automations/{{id}}
```

In the POST/PATCH request you need to delete *targetDataExtensions* array for query activity. And it works, but:

- created/updated Automation doesn't have a schedule "starting source" is empty
- it works only for Automation with only one step (may have more than one activity in this step)

If Automation contains more than one step, the response during creation is:

```
{  
   errors:[  
      {  
         message:'Invalid task collection'
      }
   ]
}
```

and during update:

```
{  
       message:'Internal Server Error',
       errorcode:0,
       documentation:'https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/error-handling.htm'
}
```

Maybe someone tried these endpoint and have an idea what I need to have to:

- be able to create/update Automation with more than one step
- have scheduled Automations

Comment: Can you post any documentation on these APIs? I do not see them on the official REST documentation. It could be as simple as these are not 'officially released' and have a few quirks or bugs in them, such as the issue you are seeing.

Comment: Hi, I haven't found any documentation regarding these APIs. But maybe someone can check to see if this is a problem with my payload or there are some bugs, because it is not released yet.

Comment: Great find!

Can you verify that the POST / PATCH options still work? Probably this is indeed still in development. 

I just tried GET, POST and PATCH.

GET works, but for


PATCH {{restEndpoint}}/automation/v1/automations/ae41cbb0-3039-430f-8c6e-47bc5ddd94ba


and


POST {{restEndpoint}}/automation/v1/automations


i receive:

    {
    "message": "Insufficient Privileges to complete this action.",
    "errorcode": 20002,
    "documentation": ""
}

Comment: @JonasLamberty for me POST and PATCH works, but:
1) only if in your payload you have Automation with only one step
2) the schedule is always empty in created automation (even if you have it in your payload)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made some investigation and think that to create/update Automation using REST, it is needed to use .json payload in this format:

```
{
    "id": "e906af34-4a19-42e9-9ce2-ac6413a77a09",
    "legacyId": "X0p0TVdZSUxWZ09sVEV0dlJiTk5CUToyNTow",
    "name": "Maciej_testAut_20190513_1721",
    "description": "ddddd",
    "key": "Maciej_testAut_20190513_1721",
    "categoryId": 409,
    "statusId": 4,
    "lastSavedDate": "2019-05-13T07:43:59.137",
    "lastSavedByName": "Maciej Barnas",
    "createdDate": "2019-05-13T06:27:06.597",
    "createdByName": "DEV integration for Metadata Tool - v2 app user",
    "updateInProgress": false,
    "steps": [
        {
            "annotation": "",
            "stepNumber": 0,
            "activities": [
                {
                    "id": "9ba08e57-57b8-4485-b219-e1ddfd6e6019",
                    "name": "Maciej_testQuery_2",
                    "description": "",
                    "activityObjectId": "fb0533a4-a7d5-4579-a766-cd7e4b047e74",
                    "objectTypeId": 300,
                    "displayOrder": 0,
                    "serializedObject": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "annotation": "",
            "stepNumber": 1,
            "activities": [
                {
                    "id": "b5cfb339-52b1-45a7-a75e-c20ac8fdecdf",
                    "name": "Maciej_testQuery_1",
                    "description": "",
                    "activityObjectId": "51f05855-88a9-403c-a3b0-d4b42ac7db91",
                    "objectTypeId": 300,
                    "displayOrder": 0,
                    "serializedObject": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "startSource": {
        "typeId": 1,
        "schedule": {
            "scheduleTypeId": 2,
            "startDate": "2019-05-13T16:00:00",
            "endDate": "2019-05-13T16:00:00",
            "rangeTypeId": 0,
            "occurrences": 1,
            "icalRecur": "FREQ=HOURLY;COUNT=1;INTERVAL=1",
            "timezoneId": 5,
            "statusId": 0
        }
    }
}
```

To create use POST, to update use PATCH. The endpoints are the same as I noticed in my question.

But as you can see the format, which you can retrieve using GET with the endpoint:

```
https://{{tenant}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/automation/v1/automations/{{id}}
```

contains e.g. "schedule" and "steps" part is different. But to create/update we need to have "startSource" and "steps" in other way.